# Are cocos2d scheduled methods run in another thread?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

We can use `scheduleUpdate` or `schedule:@selecotr(xxx)` to schedule a method to run.

Is the scheduled method run in another thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Cocos2d objects are not thread-safe and expected to run on main thread. The timer is scheduled on the main run loop. So do not block main thread under any circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [self performSelectorInBackground:…] and similar NSObject methods.

The usual caveats apply. Almost every property in cocos2d is marked "nonatomic" and is therefore not thread-safe, so you may run into common multithreading issues unless you know exactly what you're multithreading, and why you're doing it.

Comment: atomicity doesn't equal thread safety! Marking a property as atomic doesn't make it any more thread safe than marking at as nonatomic, it only guarantees that reads and writes are done atomic!